# Redux doesn't initialize state

Tags: javascript, redux

I've built up the next reducer structure:

```
//index.js

import userReducer from "./user";

const initState = {
    user: null
};

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    const {
        user
    } = state;

    if (action === "SIGN_OUT") {
        return {
            user: userReducer(null, action)
        };
    }
    return {
        user: userReducer(user, action)
    };
};

export default rootReducer;

//user.js

const initState = {
    userId: null,
    clientId: null,
    type: null
}

const userReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_USER_ID" :
            const { userId } = action;
            return {
                ...state,
                userId
            };
        case "SET_USER_DATA" :
            const { userData } = action;
            return {
                ...state,
                ...userData
            };
        default : return state;
    };
};

export default userReducer;
```

Obviously, I have more reducers, it's for to simplify the demonstration.

My logic is that if the first parameter of `userReducer` is a falsy value, it will use `initState`. In the `rootReducer` the value of `user` is null, so inside `userReducer`, it should use `initState` as state.

Unfortunately my state looks like this:

```
{ user: null }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default argument values are applied only when `undefined` or no value is passed. Passing `null` and other falsy values apart from `undefined` will override the default value. More on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Also as chrisheyn has pointed out in his answer, `if (action === "SIGN_OUT")` should be `if (action.type === "SIGN_OUT")`

Answer (score 1):

in `rootReducer` you using the parameter `action` as a string ("SIGN_OUT"). Then you pass this var into `userReducer` and you're trying to read a string from `action.type`. Thats probably the problem.

I'm not sure but it seems that you trying to combine multiple reducer in `rootReducer`, right?

Check the buildin redux function `combineReducers`: https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers

Comment: Good point at `action.type` instead of `action`, but I don't think it's relevant to the problem, as I'm not dispatching any actions, just `@@INIT` has been called, where the `rootReducer` should just pass `null`, as the first parameter of `userReducer`, which should return it's `initState`back. I'm not using combineReducers, as I want to initialize the state if `action.type === "SIGN_OUT"`